# Python ignores "if" statement, a possible scope problem?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I'm trying to write a weight converter which splits the given input and act accordingly however if statement is completely ignored. So far my search revealed that it might be a scope problem but I'm pretty green so couldn't apply any solutions to my specific code.

```
def weight_convert(answer):
      seperated = answer.split(" ")
      unit = seperated[1]
      weight = int(seperated[0])
      if unit.lower == "lbs":
         converted = weight * 0.45
      else:
         converted = weight % 0.45
      return converted, unit
```

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.  Your current code is a single function that is never called.  You have no output.

Comment: `unit.lower` is a method - it's not going to be equal to `"lbs"`, or any other string. `unit.lower()` would be the result of actually calling that method.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def weight_convert(answer):
      seperated = answer.split(" ")
      unit = seperated[1]
      weight = int(seperated[0])
      if unit.lower() == "lbs":
         converted = weight * 0.45
      else:
         converted = weight % 0.45
      return converted, unit
```

Comment: A good answer should explain what was wrong and how you fixed it.

Comment: Forgetting to use `()` on a function call is generally just closed as a typo with the explanation in a comment. Questions like these are not useful for posterity and shouldn't be answered.

Comment: Excuse me i didn't know that.